# Load next question in array using a TableView with Custom Cells & Next Button

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am new to programming & having difficulty moving to the next question/answers in my quiz array using a TableView with Custom Cells & a Next Button.

My setup:

1. Storyboard: ViewController with a TableView Controller & a Next Button
2. Custom Cells: Made with xib files
3. Question Array with a variable "questionNumber" that I want to update

Steps taken:

1. I am able to load the first item in the array
2. Created Next Button that adds 1 to the questionNumber through a variable "index"

How do I:

1. Pass this new value back to my class to update questionNumber there &
2. Have my tableView update with the next data in the array

Array

```
struct DataBrain {

var questionNumber: Int? = 0

var dataArray: [MultipleChoice] = [MultipleChoice(question: "What force is opposite to gravity?", options: ["Lift", "Thrust", "Drag", "Gravity"], rightAnswer: "Lift"), MultipleChoice(question: "What is 1 x 3", options: ["1", "2", "3", "4"], rightAnswer: "3"), MultipleChoice(question: "What does MEA stand for?", options: ["My Eating Area", "My Entering Area", "Minimum Entering Area", "None of the above"], rightAnswer: "None of the above")
```

View Controller with Table View, Custom Cells & Next Button

```
    class MultipuleChoiceViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: LongButtons!

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    var dataBrain = DataBrain()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self

        table.register(QuestionTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: QuestionTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.register(AnswerTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: AnswerTableViewCell.identifier)

    }

    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if var index = dataBrain.questionNumber {
            if index + 1 < dataBrain.dataArray.count {

                index += 1

           } else {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "MultipleChoiceToResults", sender: self)
           }

        }
    }
}

// MARK: - TableView DataSource:

extension MultipuleChoiceViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    //Number of Rows:
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if let index = dataBrain.questionNumber {
            let data = dataBrain.dataArray[index]
            if let count = data.options?.count {
                return count + 1
            }
        }
        return 0
    }

    //Return a Cell:
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: QuestionTableViewCell.identifier) as! QuestionTableViewCell

            if let index = dataBrain.questionNumber {
                let data = dataBrain.dataArray[index]
                cell.questionLabel.text = data.question
                print (dataBrain.dataArray[index])
            }

            return cell

        } else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AnswerTableViewCell.identifier) as! AnswerTableViewCell

            if let index = dataBrain.questionNumber {
                let data = dataBrain.dataArray[index]
                cell.answerLabel.text = data.options![indexPath.row - 1]
            }

            return cell

        }
    }
}

// MARK: - TableView Delegate

extension MultipuleChoiceViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

Comment: you have just one controller ?  which is `MultipuleChoiceViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Next Button Selector

```
@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if var index = dataBrain.questionNumber {
            if index + 1 < dataBrain.dataArray.count {

              index += 1
              dataBrain.questionNumber = index
              table.reloadData()

           } else {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "MultipleChoiceToResults", sender: self)
           }

        }
```